# Google Calendar Api Android Studio

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Is there a way in Android Studio to access Google Calendar API without introducing your account?

I did this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android), but I couldn't adapt that code, so any user is able to access the Google Calendar API without putting their account.

The first time I access Google Calendar I have to select my account inside my application.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it, here is my solution:

First, you have to go to [Android Quick Start (Google Calendar Api)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) , follow the instructions written in step 2 Turn on the Google Calendar API, once you do, you will get the api key.

Second, go to Google Calendar, and create a Calendar. Click over calendar name with rigth button, and select on calendar configuration. Then, in the main view, search "calendar address", on the rigth you will found a calendar id. Then, in second tab "share the calendar", click on "make the calendar public", and then save.

Copy calendarId, and apiKey, and remplace in this url, with it, you can access to values on json.

> URLhttps://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/**calendarId**/events?**apiKey**

Once you have the data in json, you can get them. In my case, I got them, thanks to this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)